# The react modal that I created closes too fast. Below is the code I have

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been watching this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10FNqoPpNbE&ab_channel=Codevolution
The code I have is this:

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import '../css/addbutton.css';

export function AddButton () {
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div className="AddButton">
            <button onClick = {() => setModalIsOpen(true)}>Add Desk Items</button>
            <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose = {()=> setModalIsOpen(false)}>
                <h2>Modal title</h2>
                <p>Modal Body</p>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={()=> setModalIsOpen(false)}>Close</button>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Comment: Is this component the main component or is it a child component?

Comment: it is a child component

Comment: Most likely, your parent component is rendering multiple times which causes the child component's state to become false

Comment: "Closes too fast" - we can't see what is controlling the modal's open state (don't rely on external links). I'd assume you need to add some sort of delay before calling `setModalIsOpen`.